# C-reading file and removing chars from output, no arrays

Tags: c

First off this is a homework assignment so lets get that out of the way, I am not looking for free code.
I am unable to use arrays for this. Strings appear to be an array in C so those are out. 
The logic is simple, if an html tag appears remove it or do \n or \n \n. No issues there.
It seems I must use the `c = getc()` function in `stdio.h` as all other functions appear to use or create arrays.

I need a tip on how to back track. 
so
`if(c == '>')`
I need to check `c-1, c-2,c-3` etc to check the previous and if I find  `<br \> than write c = \n instead of <br \>.`
The logic is simple.
My problem is `getc()` returns an int value corresponding to the ASCII code for a given character and writes said character based on the code.

for the file parsing I am currently using `do{while c != EOF`, although it seems, `for(c = getc(fp); c != EOF)` could do the same, but I have the same issue, the loop is dictated by c.
if `getc()` is the wrong approach, please let me know. I would prefer to try on my own than bug my professor. But I cannot use any arrays, which is the catcher.

Cheers.
Edit: Here is my current implementation if it helps.

```
void main()
{

    FILE *ifp, *ofp;
    int c;
    int n = 0;

    ifp = fopen("prog1in1.txt", "r");
    if(ifp == NULL){


    }
    ofp = fopen("prog1in1out.txt", "w");

    do{
        c = getc(ifp);

        if(c == '>')
            c = 'D';//just a test placeholder D holds no relevence:

            putc(c, ofp);
    }while(c !=EOF);

    for(c = getc(ifp); c!= EOF;)

    fclose(ifp);









}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What exactly are you trying to do in order to help you. If you are reading a file `fseek`
can be used to back track.

Edit:

Every time you call `getc()` you move the cursor one place so you can count where you are in
the file. With `fseek(fptr, 10, SEEK_SET)` you explicitly say to move 10 places from the   beggining of the file. So if `count` is where you are  `fseek(fptr, count - 1, SEEK_SET)`
is one place before. Does that help?

Edit2:

```
int c1,c2,c3,c4,c5;
while( (c = getc(ifp)) != EOF ){
    count++;

    if(c == '>'){
        fseek(ifp, count - 6, SEEK_SET);
        c1 = getc(ifp);
        c2 = getc(ifp);
        c3 = getc(ifp);
        c4 = getc(ifp);
        c5 = getc(ifp);

        if(c1 == '<' && c2 == 'b' && c3 == 'r' && c4 == 32 && c5 == '\'){putc(D, ofp);}

        fseek(ifp, count, SEEK_SET);
    }
}
```

Edit3

```
"<br />";
"<h1>";
"<a-href /a>";

int c,c1,c2,c3,c4,c5;
while( (c = getc(ifp)) != EOF ){
    count++;

    if(c == '<'){
        c = getc(ifp);
        count++;
        if(c == 'b'){
            c1 = getc(ifp);
            c2 = getc(ifp);
            c3 = getc(ifp);
            c4 = getc(ifp);
            if(c1 == 'r' && c2 == 32 && c3 == '/' && c4 == '>'){putc(D, ofp);}
            else{putc(c1, ofp); putc(c2, ofp); putc(c3, ofp);}

            count += 4;
        }
        else if(c == 'h'){
            ......
        }
        else if(c == 'a'){
            .......
        }
        else{
            putc('<', ofp);
            putc(c, ofp);
        }
    }
    else{
        putc(c, ofp);
    }
}
```

something like that.

valter

Comment: basically I have an input.txt file, that is coded in basic html. so it has the html tags.  I need to parse the file, and read the chars, and if a tag is found remove the tag, and in the case of line break tags do the appropriate line breaks.

The catch is no arrays can be used.

so as I parse the file I am looking for '>' and if I find one I count back to see if it is <br \ for example and ad \n. if it is say <h1> I simple discard it. 

logically its simple, its the ability to backtrack that is throwing me.

Comment: and you want to do what with that file?

Comment: sorry valter I hit enter too soon. I just finished typing it.

Comment: It does, so building on that, I can do `if(fseek(ifp, count-1, SEEK_SET) == \ && ...)`
Than the last thing to resolve is replacing the already placed characters... 

However if I count ahead I can preemtive replace them.

Am I correct?

Comment: First, fseek just moves the "cursor" in the file. What you wrote is wrong. You have to call getc() again. Are\ you replacing characters in the file or are you just count them?

Comment: Replacing. I was trying to use a bit of shorthand with the ...
`If I find <p> insert \n \n` There are other things that would be replaced but that is just one.
I suppose my implementation would follow this logic, with proper syntax of course.
counting ahead this way.
`if(c == `<`)
if(fseek(ifp, count +1, SEEK_CUR) == 'p' && fseek(ifp, count +2, SEEK_CUR) == '>')
c = '\n' + '\n')`
The second If is nested in the first. I am not great with the formatting on this site, so please forgive that.

Comment: Edit: I did not read fully what you posted, so when I check the next position I call getc() on that seek and do another if and call it and again and again. Hmm that could get bulky.

Comment: Thank you valter. That was a bit more help than I expected. Greatly appreciated.

Comment: So you basically you are copying the one txt file to another skiping  some strings like <br \> , <h1> etc. Am i right?

Comment: that is correct. The only other thing that gets skipped, or rather modified is the <a-href.../a> and for that one I just leave the file name, so foobar.html is just foobar.
I can figure that part out. You have provided more than enough help. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You could use variables c3, c2, c1, etc. and shift values down through that chain as you read characters in; it isn't an "array", it just functions as one.

And actually, I don't think you need backtracking. A bit of buffering, but with a suitable state machine...

Comment: that would work, although he states he "prefers" counting backwards. Given that this is done in a loop based on a per character iteration, how would I implement that or better a point to a reference, that way I can implement it without it given to me.